# Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.Barrier"

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to use the `Barrier` view in `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/buttonBarrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="top"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="answer1Button,answer2Button"
    />
```

It works fine in the IDE, and I get Barrier-specific lint messages. But when I run the app, it crashes trying to inflate the layout containing the Barrier:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.Barrier"
```

I am using AndroidX ConstraintLayout 1.1.3:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

What's happening here?

Comment: Please avoid duplicate posts! A.B.C.: ALWAYS. BE. SEARCHING.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The xml tag is `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier` in the latest AndroidX version.